# Responsive image with hover effect

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have an image with a hover effect that looks like this:

```
<img src="jb-400x500.jpg" alt="yada" width="400" height="500" onmouseover="this.src='jb-400x500-2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='jb-400x500.jpg';" />
```

This works fine, except I would like for only the second image (jb-400x500-2.jpg) to be displayed for mobile viewers. I tried using `srcset` to achieve this, but doing so gets rid of the mouseover effect for desktop viewers. Is there any way to make the two work together?

Thanks.

Comment: but how can you hover on a mobile?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I think he means he wants it to default to the second image on mobile. Also, on iDevices, you can tap to hover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you include a `srcset` on a browser that supports it, the `src` attribute will be ignored. So your script will need to change the `srcset` as well as, or instead of, the `src` attribute. E.g.

```
<img src="jb-400x500.jpg" alt="yada" width="400" height="500"
  srcset="jb-400x500-2.jpg 720w,jb-400x500.jpg 1x"
  onmouseover="this.setAttribute('srcset','jb-400x500-2.jpg 720w,jb-400x500-2.jpg 1x');"
  onmouseout="this.setAttribute('srcset','jb-400x500-2.jpg 720w,jb-400x500.jpg 1x');" />
```

Comment: Your solution and Marco Del Valle's solution both worked perfectly. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add some JavaScript via the `<script>` tag at the bottom of your HTML document.

For starters, you have to add an `id` attribute to your image so we can select it.

```
<img src="jb-400x500.jpg" id="image-1" alt="yada" width="400" height="500" />
```

Secondly, we'll use Javascript to detect if you're using a touch device, and apply the necessary behaviors to your image element:

```
<script>
    // Detect if browser enables touch events
    var isTouchDevice = "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement;
    // Select your image
    var image1 = document.getElementById("image-1");

    if(isTouchDevice){ // If it's touch, change the image src
        image1.src = "jb-400x500-2.jpg";
    }else{ // If it's not touch, assign mouseover and mouseout events
        image1.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
            image1.src = "jb-400x500-2.jpg";
        });
        image1.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {
            image1.src = "jb-400x500.jpg";
        });
    }
</script>
```

Remember to add your `<script>` at the bottom of your document, right before you close `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use css and @media-query to achieve this effect

Basically I can tell that you need to add two images with different hover effects – one for desktop and one for mobile
And hide one of them depending on screen resolution with css.